# Pandas Efficiency -- Is there a faster way to slice thousands of times?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Appreciate any help from the community on this.  I've been toying with it for a few days now.

I have 2 dataframes, df1 & df2.  The first dataframe will always be 1 min data about 20-30 thousand rows.  The second dataframe will contain random times with associated relevant data & will always be relatively small (1000-4000 rows x 4 or 5 columns).  I'm working through df1 with itertuples in order to perform a time specific slice (trailing).  This process gets repeated thousands of times, & the single slice line below (df3 = df2...) is causing over 50% of the runtime.  Simply adding a couple slicing criteria in the single line below can have 30+% increases on the final runtimes which run hours long!

I've considered trying pandas 'query', but have read it really only helps on larger dataframes.  My thought is that it may be better to reduce df2 into a numpy array, simple python list, or other since it is always fairly short, though I think I'll need it back into a dataframe for subsequent sorting, summations, and vector multiplications that come afterward in the primary code.  I did succeed in utilizing concurrent futures on a 12 core setup, which increased speed about 5X for my overall application, though I'm still talking hours of runtime.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Example code illustrating the issue:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import random
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, timezone

def random_dates(start, end, n=10):
    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

dfsize = 34000
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=dfsize, freq='1min'), 'val':np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=dfsize)})   

sizedf = 3000
start = pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2010-01-24')
test_list = [5, 30]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':random_dates(start,end, sizedf), 'a':np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=sizedf), 'b':np.random.choice(test_list, sizedf), 'c':np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=sizedf), 'd':np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=sizedf), 'e':np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=sizedf)})
df2.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
daysback5 = 3
daysback30 = 8

#%%timeit -r1   #time this section here:
#Slow portion here - Performing ~4000+ slices on a dataframe (df2) which is ~1000 to 3000 rows -- Some slowdown due to itertuples, which don't think is avoidable
for line, row in enumerate(df1.itertuples(index=False), 0):
    if row.datetime.minute % 5 ==0: 
        #Lion's share of the slowdown:
        df3 = df2[(df2['a']<=row.val*1.25) & (df2['a']>=row.val*.75) & (df2.index<=row.datetime) & (((df2.index>=row.datetime-timedelta(days=daysback30)) & (df2['b']==30)) | ((df2.index>=row.datetime-timedelta(days=daysback5)) & (df2['b']==5))) ].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
```

Time of slow part:

> 8.53 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

```
df1:
      datetime              val
0   2010-01-01 00:00:00 58.990147
1   2010-01-01 00:01:00 27.457308
2   2010-01-01 00:02:00 20.657251
3   2010-01-01 00:03:00 36.416561
4   2010-01-01 00:04:00 71.398897
... ... ...
33995   2010-01-24 14:35:00 77.763085
33996   2010-01-24 14:36:00 21.151239
33997   2010-01-24 14:37:00 83.741844
33998   2010-01-24 14:38:00 93.370216
33999   2010-01-24 14:39:00 99.720858
34000 rows × 2 columns
```

df2:

```
                               a     b          c     d   e
datetime                    
2010-01-03 23:38:13 22.363251   30  81.158073   21.806457   11.116421
2010-01-09 16:27:32 78.952070   5   27.045279   29.471537   29.559228
2010-01-13 04:49:57 85.985935   30  79.206437   29.711683   74.454446
2010-01-07 22:29:22 36.009752   30  43.072552   77.646257   57.208626
2010-01-15 09:33:02 13.653679   5   87.987849   37.433810   53.768334
... ... ... ... ... ...
2010-01-12 07:36:42 30.328512   5   81.281791   14.046032   38.288534
2010-01-08 20:26:31 80.911904   30  32.524414   80.571806   26.234552
2010-01-14 08:32:01 12.198825   5   94.270709   27.255914   87.054685
2010-01-06 03:25:09 82.591519   5   91.160917   79.042083   17.831732
2010-01-07 14:32:47 38.337405   30  10.619032   32.557640   87.890791
3000 rows × 5 columns
```

Comment: How did you get your code to run in 8.5s? It refuses to run within minutes on my system.

Comment: ??   It's just in VS Code's Jupyter Notebook.  It is a very new computer w an AMD Ryzen 9 3900.  Anaconda environment Python 3.7.8.  I have seen some posts that some Pandas functions w newer Python versions enable multi-threading??

Answer (score 1):

Actually, cross merge and query works pretty well for your data size:

```
(df1[df1.datetime.dt.minute % 5==0].assign(dummy=1)
    .merge(df2.reset_index().assign(dummy=1),
           on='dummy', suffixes=['_1','_2'])
    .query('val*1.25 >= a >= val*.75 and datetime_2 <= datetime_1 ')
    .loc[lambda x: ((x.datetime_2 >= x.datetime_1 - daysback30) & x['b'].eq(30) )
                  |((x.datetime_2>= x.datetime_1 - daysback5) & (x['b']==5))]
)
```

which takes about on my system:

```
2.05 s ± 60.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 3 loops each)
```

where your code runs for about `10s`.

Comment: Thanks Quang.  This was helpful.  I'm going to have to continue to think about how I could possibly perform the rest of the code with having an entire dataframe like this.  The above generates a dataframe of over a million rows & subsequently iterlooping with selections on just the dates are extremely slow by comparison.  I tried utilizing just the 'query' portion in the existing iterloop & got a slower, 18.5 sec -- Really like the syntax.  Introduced me to some new features!!